# How to implement sqlalchemy aggregate functions in flask datatables (Server Side)?

Tags: python, flask, datatables, flask-sqlalchemy, server-side

I am using SqlAlchemy-Datatables for implementing server side datatables.

I am not able to define ColumnsDT and query for aggregate functions like sum, count, etc. on server side for sqlalchemy datatables. I tried

```
columns = [
    ColumnDT(Timepass.user_name),
    ColumnDT(func.sum(Timepass.income).label('Sum'))
]
results = db.session.query(Timepass.user_name, func.sum(Timepass.income).label('Sum')).group_by(Timepass.user_name)
params = request.args.to_dict()
rowTable = DataTables(params, results, columns)
return jsonify(rowTable.output_result())
```

I get the following error : **DataTables warning: table id=example - (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 4: ...ST(timepass.user_name AS TEXT) ILIKE '%%' OR CAST(sum(timepa...**

Answer (score 2):

Got help from https://github.com/Pegase745/sqlalchemy-datatables/issues/93. The key thing to notice here is the global_search = False parameter. If it is not used, it throws error in where clause saying aggregate functions cannot be used in Where clause..

```
columns = [
    ColumnDT(Timepass.user_name),
    ColumnDT(func.sum(Timepass.income).label('Sum'), global_search=False),
    ColumnDT(func.count(Timepass.user_name).label('Count'), global_search=False)
]
query = session.query(Timepass.user_name, func.sum(Timepass.income).label('Sum'),
                      func.count(Timepass.user_name).label('Count')).group_by(Timepass.user_name)

params = request.args.to_dict()

rowTable = DataTables(params, query, columns)

return jsonify(rowTable.output_result())
```